# Why are static method signatures incompatible if I am not involving an interface or abstract class?

Tags: php

Base class and inherited setup

```php
class A
{
  static public function meow(string $x,string $y="default"){}
}

class B extends A
{
  static public function meow(string $y="default"){}
}
```

Output

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of B::meow(string $y = 'default') must be compatible with A::meow(string $x, string $y = 'default') in ...
```

I have seen other similar issues that involve abstract classes or interfaces, which is not the case here.

Why am I forced to define the exact same parameters?

Comment: Although not an answer, there was [some discussion](https://externals.io/message/110562) about it, since LSP arguably doesn’t apply to static methods. I think the “why”  is that it was implemented across the board, regardless static or even private. The latter had the [restriction removed in 8.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/inheritance_private_methods).

Answer (score 0):

In **Liskov Substitution Principle(LSP)**, The behavior of the sub-classes must respect the contract established in the super-class.

There cannot be a method in the subclass that goes against a behavior of the base class. This is called Historical Constraint.

Have a look on full article about [**LSP**](https://dev.to/evrtrabajo/solid-in-php-d8e)

Comment: This is not enforced in constructors